# Sharing behavior when uploading data with owner, created by

Tags: lookup, data-loader, sharing, insufficient-privileges

- Uploaded some contacts where the Owner, Created By fields set to user
  abc(I enabled audit fields for my API only user)
- Then tried uploading
  custom object X__c where it has a lookup to contact, Owner and
  Created By set to same user abc
- Experienced

> insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

for lookup contact Ids eventhough the owner for both records are same.

Is it required to have the sharing access to API only user as well eventhough the owner is specified in the csv sheet being  uploading?

Comment: you are logged in with 'abc' user?

Comment: Your "API Only User" profile needs to have "view all" access on Contacts to assign it for the lookup field unless "abc" user and the "API Only User" are the same.

Comment: Thanks both, my API only user and abc user are different and from different profiles. I was thinking since contacts are owned by abc, the X__c being uploaded where owned by abc himself would be a valid insertion.